# Debugging a webpage for IE 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, web-developer-toolbar

I am testing a web page for IE 7. I am currently using IE Tester to test it. I have an issue where a `div` that is visible on other browsers is not visible in IE 7. I have tried to increase the `z-index` to see if that was the issue but I have had no luck.

The main reason I am struggling is because I cannot figure out what is actually wrong, and why the `div` is not showing up like I want it to. Usually I do all my css work with help from debugging tools like *firebug* or the google and opera equivalents, but I am noticing there is really little to nothing I can do with the IE Tester debugger.

**In short** Is there a decent debugging tool I can use to debug `css` in IE 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used IE8+.

With the Developer Tools (F12) included in IE8  you can switch to the IE7 rendering engine.
This will allow you view the webpage as it will appear in IE7 but give you access to the debugging mode and console available with IE8+ browsers.

Comment: Note that this is also available in IE9

Answer (score 2):

In short, **Yes**, http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Super Preview, a part of Microsoft Expression Web. It lets you test all versions of IE as well as other browsers side by side and allow you to compare differences.

Heres the Link:

http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/SuperPreview_Overview.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[IE Developer Toolbar (IEDevToolBarSetup.msi)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359) is the official Microsoft tool for debugging CSS in IE6 and IE7.